# Overriding a has_many association getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A user can have several cars -

- `User: has_many :cars`
- `Car: belongs_to :user`

Every time I call `@user.cars` it returns the list of `cars` in default search order.

If I wanted the association sorted on some arbitrary field, I could do

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, -> { order :num_wheels }
end
```

But let's say my ordering logic is complex and I want to just override the association getter to implement my own logic

I try something something like -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars

  def cars
    # Pretend this is complex logic
    cars.order(:num_wheels)
  end
end
```

However that obviously fails because you can't reference the original `cars` from inside the overridden `cars` method without it looping infinitely.

Is there a way to reference the "original" getter from inside my overridden getter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use super:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars

  def cars
    # Pretend this is complex logic
    super.order(:num_wheels)
  end
end
```

when you use a macro like has_many, Rails dynamically creates a module(which could be accessed by User.generated_association_methods).In your case, define the accessors and readers(such as "cars" in your case, which could be accessed by User.generated_association_methods.instance_methods). This module becomes the ancestor of your User class, so you can access the reader method(cars) by "super" in your own cars method.

Answer (score 3):

With my understanding I believe what has_many is essentially doing is:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars

  # is essentially
  def cars
    Car.where(user_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

So when a user wants to list all the cars it would still be User.cars. When using ActiveRecord the has_many is assuming both the method name of cars and the foreign keys associated.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  def cars
    Car.where(user_id: id).order(:num_wheels)
  end
end
```

Comment: Not only doesn't answer the question and adds superfluous code, that new code uses the ID of the Car to look for some `user_id` property? Entirely unrelated _and_ buggy.
Plus zero description of your answer at all. Code-only answers are bad.
This isn't even worth keeping around imo.

Comment: The result is ok. But you are right @Tim, This answer performance is not good and not clear enough to use. We should consider defining scopes in `Car.rb` and use chain instead of override `cars` like this. Thank you for your comment.