# rails4 has_one association scope with where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, associations, has-one

I am developing a Product model that has an has_one association to itself including a raw material record. And the model returns data through REST API. I am using Active Model Serializer instead of JBuilder.

Product model has a 'code' field that contain a product code in string:

```
'001-000-01-01' (This is a product.)
'001-000-00-01' (This is a material.)
```

Only difference between two codes is the third number from right. '1' is product. '0' is material. I want to include a "raw_material" record when retrieving a product record. So, I try to set has_one  association with scope that has a "where" clause (later I can compose a query to get a material from a product code). Now I simply pass "product" object in lambda and use it in where.

First I write in def raw_material, this works. However, I don't know how to pass an object to def and use it in where clause. Therefore I come up with the scope pattern in has_one, however it returns an error even though it generates exactly the same SELECT as the def pattern. I get "NoMethodError" instead.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :supplies, ->{order('row_order ASC') }, primary_key: :code, foreign_key: :product_code
  #This Works!
  #has_one :raw_material, class_name: 'Product', primary_key: :code, foreign_key: :code
  #This Works!
  #has_one :raw_material
  #Does not work. Why?
  has_one :raw_material, ->(product) { where('code = ?', product.code).take }, class_name: 'Product'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplies, allow_destroy: true

  #def raw_material
  #  Product.where('code = ?', '001-000-01-01').take
  #end
end
```

The "def" pattern works:

```
Started GET "/products/1.json" for ::1 at 2016-10-05 21:48:15 +0900
Processing by ProductsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   Supply Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "supplies".* FROM "supplies" WHERE "supplies"."product_code" = ?  ORDER BY row_order ASC  [["product_code", "031-052-00-01"]]
[active_model_serializers]   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (code = '001-000-01-01') LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ProductSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (6.71ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 9.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

However, the scope pattern does not work:

```
Started GET "/products/1.json" for ::1 at 2016-10-06 08:19:13 +0900
Processing by ProductsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   Supply Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "supplies".* FROM "supplies" WHERE "supplies"."product_code" = ?  ORDER BY row_order ASC  [["product_code", "031-052-00-01"]]
[active_model_serializers]   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (code = '031-052-00-01') LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ProductSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (10.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `except' for #<Product:0x007fe97b090418>):
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in show'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:14:in `show'


  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.8ms)
```

Product Controller simply defines show like this:

```
# GET /products/1
# GET /products/1.json
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render json: @product, include: ['raw_material']
    end
  end
end
```

product_serializer.rb is:

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(*Product.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
  has_one :raw_material
end
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I solved this issue myself. Please check my answer below. Thank all who wrote solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the has_one :raw_material as follows.

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(*Product.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))

  has_one :raw_material do
    Product.where(code: object.code)
  end

end
```

Comment: This is simple enough to test it immediately. But it does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this myself. Since I don't have to write this in a line, the def(method) pattern is the best bet. How to override "has_many" could help my issue.

[Overriding a has_many association getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782820/overriding-a-has-many-association-getter)

"self" can be used for has_one to get an object inside def.

```
has_one :raw_material

def raw_material
  Product.where('code like ?', (self.code)[0,9] + '_' + (self.code)[10,3]).take
end
```

This works and can generate any dataset you like in a Model.

Answer (score -2):

```
 # Does not work. Why?
 has_one :raw_material ->(product) { where('code = ?', product.code).take }...
```

because you are trying to define a scope here... not an association. if you want a scope, use a scope eg:

```
scope :raw_material ->(product) { where('code = ?', product.code).first }
```

if you want an association, then use an association eg

```
has_one :raw_material, class_name: 'Product', primary_key: :code, foreign_key: :code
```

don't try to mix the two.

Comment: Thank you. If scope: is used, I have to call it from my controller. And nested json data is omitted in this way. That's the reason I avoid calling it from a controller. It seems OK to call "scope" regarding to Rails doc.   http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Comment: You can include things in your json by using `include` though... so I'm not sure how you mean that it's omitted: https://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods

Comment: I don't remember the exact issue. Nested data wasn't preloaded when REST API was called or something. It might be worked in MVC. Maybe I'm wrong. If I could use "find" in controller, your way also could be good way to go.

Comment: it's really hard to debug a verbal description of code...  (you have a very firm idea of what that code looks like in your head, but it's difficult to communicate that outside). instead of describing what you could/couldn't do - shows us the different examples as actual code by adding them to the end of your question :)